# How to count custom data by custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2

i have data array like this

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Ärzte" ["id"]=> string(2) "53" } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(15) "Bijouteriewaren" ["id"]=> string(2) "58" } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Optiker" ["id"]=> string(3) "110" } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(31) "Reisebüros & Reiseveranstalter" ["id"]=> string(3) "120" } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(2) "DJ" ["id"]=> string(2) "66" } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Damenmoden" ["id"]=> string(2) "65" } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(2) "DJ" ["id"]=> string(2) "66" } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(2) "DJ" ["id"]=> string(2) "66" } }
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(22) "Bordelle & Laufhäuser" ["id"]=> string(2) "61" } }
```

How to count data by id?

My code

```
$getBranche = $block->getBranchesBySellerId($subAccount['seller_id']);
foreach ($getBranche as $branche) {
?>
     <a href="<?php echo $branche['link'] ?>"><?php echo $branche['name'] ?></a>
<?php
}
```

My function getBranchesBySellerId()

```
public function getBranchesBySellerId($sellerId) {
    $nameBranche = $this->getBranche->getBrancheByIdSeller($sellerId);
    $id = $this->getBranche->getIdBranche($nameBranche);
    $selectedBranches[] = [
        'name' => $nameBranche,
        'id' => $id,
        'link' => $this->getUrl('branche/collection') . '?branche=' . $id
    ];
    return $selectedBranches;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Code : $this->getBranche->getBrancheByIdSeller();

```
public function getBrancheByIdSeller($sellerId){
    $customer = $this->customerModel->load($sellerId);
    $branch = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute(self::ATTRIBUTE_SERVICES)->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);
    return $branch;
}
```

It get all branche

EX : Count " ID = 66 " = 3

Comment: Can you please add your code which you have tried?

Comment: hi  Rohan Hapani , please check my code

Comment: Add whole file code where getBranchesBySellerId() available.

Comment: hi Rohan Hapani , please check updated question